# S4 constructor initialize and prototype

Tags: r, validation, constructor, r-s4

I am trying to build a S4 object by calling the validity method in the constructor.

```
setClass("Person", slot = c(Age = "numeric"))

validityPerson<-function(object){
    if(object@Age < 0)return("Age cannot be negative")
TRUE
}
setValidity("Person", validityPerson)
setMethod("initialize","Person", function(.Object,...){
validObject(.Object)
.Object
})
```

This code is problematic because I get

```
new("Person", Age = 12)
#Error in if (object@Age < 0) return("Age cannot be negative") : 
#argument is of length zero
```

Of course I would like the Age to be equal to 12. This is a toy example, but I am trying to understand how I can have an initialize method that potentially can do all sort of other initialisations and then check that it is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example on the `?initialize` help page, you need to actually initialize the object otherwise none of the slots will be filled. Otherwise those `...` are just gobbling up the parameters and not doing anything with them. You can invoke the default initialize with `callNextMethod`

```
setMethod("initialize", "Person", function(.Object, ...) {
    .Object <- callNextMethod()
    validObject(.Object)
    .Object
})
```

Comment: Thx for pointing out. Although it is now working, I still dont quite get this line. I thought 'callNextMethod()' would be only necesseray if there is inheritance involved. So why I do need it in this case?

Comment: If you don't call `callnextMethod()` you need to do the work of taking all the parameters that were passed to the initialize function and assigning them to slots. You've defined your function to have a `...` to capture the `Age=` parameter but you never do anything with it. In this case `callNextMethod` will use the `...` to assign to slots for you.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: One more question on this topic. Now that I can create an object `James = new("Person", Age = 12)`.  I can still "wrong" assignments such as `James@Age = -1`, without raising an error. How can I control for this?

Comment: Note that that this question is partially answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448198/does-r-copy-unevaluated-slots-in-s4-classes-on-assignment/).Nevertheless it would be heplful to know if `SetValidity` can be called when using `@`

Answer (score 2):

`setClass` actually does a lot of this work for you. If you modify your first line to capture the return:

`setClass("Person", slot = c(Age = "numeric")) -> Person`

then you can instantiate objects with

`Person(Age=12)`.